# Newton's Third Law in Latex

Tags: math-mode, equations, mathspec, physics

Sorry for my naive question, but I'm trying to write Newton's third law this way and I don't understand why it doesn't look right. There is perhaps a problem with the subscripts.

This is what a I want:

[image]

And this is what I am writing

$F_\vec{AB}=-F_\vec{BA}F_AB = F_BA $

But for some reason he considers it all a subscript from the first one...

Comment: Scopes are just confused in your code. Just do: $F_{\vec{AB}}=-F_{\vec{BA}}F_{AB} = F_{BA}$

Comment: Solved, thanks for the quick response! =D

Answer (score 3):

I add a best output for the arrows, using `esvect` package: https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/esvect/esvect.pdf

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{esvect}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \vv{F}_{\!AB}=-\vv{F}_{\!BA}, \quad F_{AB} = F_{BA} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum 1/17/2023**: After the comment of the nice user @barbara beeton, I add the arrows in subscript mode, but not over the *F*.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{esvect}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  {F}_{\vv{\!AB}}=-{F}_{\vv{\!BA}}, \quad F_{AB} = F_{BA} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very nice, but is not what the OP wanted.  See OP's comment above,

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes I have seen. But I wanted give a better output with esvect package.

Comment: That's not what I meant,  The vector arrow should be over the subscript, not over the *F*.  That should be possible with `esvect`, and if you make it, this would be a better answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton As you can very well observe some issues or simple solution questions I do not understand because of the lack of basic fundamentals of the English language. Now I understand. Thank you very much.